# Chaining Maybe in rxjava for "else" or "coallesce"

Tags: rx-java

I'm fairly new to rxjava, so apologies if this is a silly question.  I have two Maybes (call them A and B) that I want to compose in such a way that I get a 3rd Maybe.

If A succeeds, I want my composite to succeed with that same value.  If A errors, I want my composite to error with that same throwable.  If A completes without emitting a value, I want to then delegate to B.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: It is called [switchIfEmpty](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#switchIfEmpty(io.reactivex.MaybeSource))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about specific errors in A, you can use the following:

```
A
.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
.switchIfEmpty(B)
```